# SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile"

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I'm getting an error "SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile"", whenever i try to run this command in terminal that is `flutter run --release`. Before i run this command multiple times but no error. Then i checked `key.properties` inside `android` folder and surprisingly that file is missing. I remembered that file was there but now it is missing and even in `Github`. Now i don't remember my `keyAlias` , `keyPassword` & `storePassword`. How i solve this issue? i mean how i get those keyalias and password ?

> Build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.test.app"
        minSdkVersion 21
        multiDexEnabled true
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:28.4.0')
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
}
```

Comment: You can generate new one if you haven’t published any app on play store yet. If you have then you'll have to either find existing keystore properties or last option is to create new app on play store and publish again..

Comment: @JeelVankhede My app is published on play store (but in Internal Testing)
I tried to find in my local machine but could not.

Comment: See if you had opt-in for this https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en#zippy= whether this has any kind of recovery mechanism or something..

Answer (score 2):

key.properties file must add to your project for more info visit
https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android

Answer (score 1):

> in android/key.properties

for my case...

```
storePassword=**********
keyPassword=**********
keyAlias=upload
storeFile=E:\\upload-keystore.jks
```

In window try to write path as

```
storeFile=C:\\Users\\<Your user folder>\\upload-keystore.jks
instead of C:\Users\<Your user folder>\upload-keystore.jks

The important note is "\\" in a path.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I received this message on CI build only. The reason for that is the fact that I used git-crypt to encrypt keys.properties file. I used the wrong name for decrypting the file by git-crypt. I did not have a problem with my local builds because the file was already decrypted.

Therefore, this message displays when the build system is unable to read the keys.properties file.

This is the way I usually do in order to read the keys.properties file.

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('./keystore/key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystorePropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        keystoreProperties.load(reader)
    }
}
```

and then

```
signingConfigs {
        debug {
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
            storeFile file('../keystore/debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
        }

        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you use signingConfigs for debug? I'm asking, because Android Studio does it for me locally.

Comment: @LSR, to keep the build config the same among developers. Your way is fine if you are the only developer.